# Override mappings globally

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a domain model that is mapped via conventions and `IAutoMappingOverride<T>` classes to a legacy Oracle database.

As such, for every entity that is to be written to the database, there exists an `IAutoMappingOverride<T>` class that specifies the sequence to use for the PK:

```
mapping.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Sequence("SQ_BATCHES_ID");
```

Now, I am currently trying to track down a bug and would like to test that schema with a different database, specifically with an in-memory SQLite database.

The problem is that SQLite doesn't support sequences.

Is it possible to globally override the configuration?
Something along the lines of: "When ID is generated by a sequence, use identity instead".

What I don't want to do is to use a different set of `IAutoMappingOverride<T>` implementations, because most of the time, the mapping of the ID is not the only thing that is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ExposeConfiguration` you can do pretty much everything with the generated configuration. Even changing the generators:

```
private void OverrideGenerators(Configuration config)
{
    var identifiers =
        config.ClassMappings.Select(x => x.Identifier)
                .OfType<SimpleValue>()
                .Where(x => x.IdentifierGeneratorStrategy
                             .StartsWith("sequence"));
    foreach (var identifier in identifiers)
    {
        identifier.IdentifierGeneratorProperties.Remove("sequence");
        identifier.IdentifierGeneratorStrategy = "identity";
    } 
}
```